# How to hook up search results page to a back-end page?

Tags: customization, pages, templates, search

On my site, editors can upload "banner" images to every page on the site. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to link the search results page to a back-end page (ie the page that appears at example.com/?s=searchterm).

Does anyone have any tips on making a page in the back-end "link up" to the search results page so a user could upload a banner to a page in the back-end admin and have it appear on the search results page?

I did some googling and found this page on Wordpress' codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page however the methods described there don't seem to be working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably it's me, but I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Can you give an example?

Comment: @G.M. Sure, similar to what I said in the original post, let's say you have a site where an admin can upload a unique banner image to every single page on the site. How do you give them a page in the back-end where they can upload a banner that will appear on the search results page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand well, you want to use a specific page as search results page.

This is a bit tricky, because when you are on search page, current query is the one created by the search term in the url, but to get a specific page you need a query for that page.

So you need 2 queries. This is not ideal about performance, and probably using a different way to link banner to pages you can solve this problem in a more efficent way.

However, let's answer you question.

When you are in search result page WordPress uses the `search.php` template to show the results. See [WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

If `search.php` is not there, your theme is using `index.php` to show search results, in this case duplicate the `index.php` renaming the copy `search.php`: in this way you have a specific template for search results.

If you are using a theme developed by third party, is a good idea doing everything in a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), in this way when you update theme you'll not lose the changes.

You don't say how you are linking banner to pages, I assume you upload banners as featured images, if you do it differently (e.g. using custom fields), edit the code accordingly.

Open your `search.php` and where you want to show the banner use:

```
global $post;
$post = get_page_by_path('search');
setup_postdata($post);
// now the page with slug 'search' is treated as it was the current page
// so retrieve the banner just like you do in normal page
// I'll use page featured image
the_post_thumbnail();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now, you have to go in your dashboard, create a page and assign it the slug 'search'. That slug is assigned automatically if you use 'Search' as title.

Finally add the banner to that page.